# GCC inline assembly

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I tried an example from `GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO`

```
int main(void)
{
    int foo = 10, bar=15;
    _asm__volatile_( "addl %%ebx,%%eax;\n"
                   :"=a"(foo)
                   :"a"(foo), "b"(bar));
    printf("foo+bar+%d\n",foo);
    return 0;
 }
```

the above code gives me this `error`  :  `add_two.c:8:3: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token`.

where have i gone wrong? I am working on `ubuntu 12.04`.

Comment: Just a note: don't use `__volatile__` here. The `asm` 'output' writes to `foo`, using `foo` and `bar` in a way that the compiler doesn't know about. Hence, it is not free to 'optimize' the `asm` statement away. Also, `%ebx` might not be available for IA32 ELF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
_asm__volatile_( "addl %%ebx,%%eax;\n"
```

...is not correct syntax. **asm** and **volatile** are separate keywords.

```
__asm__ __volatile__( "addl %%ebx,%%eax;\n"
```

...compiles (and executes with correct result).